# как сделать импорт с mysql базы в mssql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

как это можно реализовать? ладно импорт почти любым форматом с mysql базы через php могу сделать, а дальше как? мне еще надо сделать cron чтобы раз в сутки брал и добавлял с одной базы в другую.
Подскажите пожалуйста какими методами это можно реализовать? Можно ли все это реализовать через php?

Comment: Это одна таблица или вся база данных?

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky с одной таблицы надо добавлять в другую таблицу.

Comment: В таком случае вы можете экспортировать эту таблицу базы данных как файл XML. После этого загрузите его в SQL Server.

Comment: Да не нужен тут PHP. На MS SQL создаёте Linked Server к MySQL, и из ежесуточного плана обслуживания (CRON тоже не нужен) забираете нужные данные и раскладываете куда надо с какой надо обработкой.

Comment: @Akina есть более точная документация? у нас стоит w 2012 server. Ниразу не работал, поэтому искал варианты в php)

Comment: *есть более точная документация?* Есть. BOL называется. См. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ff772782(v=sql.110) и рядом.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, для MySQL нет поставщика OLE DB Provider.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Гуголь на запрос "sql server linked server to mysql" вообще-то просто захлёбывается ссылками... и что самое забавное - работает. Вот, например, [это](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4570/access-mysql-data-from-sql-server-via-a-linked-server/)

Answer (score 0):

**XML**

```
<DATA FORMAT_VERSION="1.0">
    <RECORD>    
        <NAME>МІЖНАРОДНА ГРОМАДСЬКА ОРГАНІЗАЦІЯ МІЖНАРОДНА АКАДЕМІЯ БІОЕНЕРГОТЕХНОЛОГІЙ</NAME>
        <SHORT_NAME>МАБЕТ</SHORT_NAME>
        <EDRPOU>00011601</EDRPOU>
        <ADDRESS>01001, м.Київ, Шевченківський район, ВУЛИЦЯ ПРОРІЗНА, будинок 8, офіс 426</ADDRESS>
        <STAN>зареєстровано</STAN>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <NAME>МІЖНАРОДНА ГРОМАДСЬКА ОРГАНІЗАЦІЯ МІЖНАРОДНА АКАДЕМІЯ БІОЕНЕРГОТЕХНОЛОГІЙ</NAME>
        <SHORT_NAME>МАБЕТ</SHORT_NAME>
        <EDRPOU>00011602</EDRPOU>
        <ADDRESS>01001, м.Київ, Шевченківський район, ВУЛИЦЯ ПРОРІЗНА, будинок 8, офіс 426</ADDRESS>
        <STAN>зареєстровано</STAN>
    </RECORD>
</DATA>
```

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
   ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   Code NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   ShortName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   [Name] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   LegalAddress NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   [Status] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH XmlFile (xmlData) AS
(
   SELECT TRY_CAST(BulkColumn AS XML) 
   FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'c:\Users\Yitzhak\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\Ukraine.xml', CODEPAGE = '65001', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
)
INSERT INTO @tbl (Code, ShortName, [Name], LegalAddress, [Status])
SELECT c.value('(EDRPOU/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(50)') AS [Code]
   , c.value('(SHORT_NAME/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(100)') AS [ShortName]
   , c.value('(NAME/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(100)') AS [Name]
   , c.value('(ADDRESS/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(100)') AS [LegalAddress]
   , c.value('(STAN/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(50)') AS [Status]
FROM XmlFile CROSS APPLY xmlData.nodes('/DATA/RECORD') AS t(c);

-- test
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

Comment: а где код который отвечает за расписание? надо раз в сутки делать, но для проверки хочу сделать раз в 1-5 минут

Comment: Обычно это делается через SQL Server Agent

Comment: сразу вопрос
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'c:\Users\Yitzhak\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\Ukraine.xml', CODEPAGE = '65001', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
эир может быть ссылкой?

Comment: К сожалению нет. Он не принимает переменную для пути к файлу.